# Django: How to migrate dynamic models made at runtime

Tags: python, django

In my Django app, a specific user input will result in the creation of a new model. Here is the code I am using to create the model and register it.

```
model = type(model_name, (ExistingModel,), attrs)
admin.site.register(model, admin_options)

from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches
from django.utils.module_loading import import_module
reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
clear_url_caches()
```

This successfully creates the new model, however, when I click on the model to see the table on the admin page, I get the following error:

> relation "ExistingModel_NewModel" does not exist

This usually means that the new model changes have not been migrated. How can I migrate dynamically created models in Django to see their corresponding data tables?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A simple solution worked for me. I ended up running the `makemigrations` and `migrate` management commands like so, after creating the dynamic model:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
call_command('makemigrations')
call_command('migrate')
```

Answer (score 3):

Subprocess can migrate your model using migrate command. So try this it will work

```
import subprocess
command = 'python manage.py migrate'
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(command)
```

Read also this https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels If it can help for create dynamic model

Comment: First thanks for the good answer! It shows you completely understand my issue! So I added this once before reloading the urls (after register) and once after reload. In both cases, it still gives the same error. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: did you check output of stdout and stderr variables?