# DJango: Can we use ALTER TABLE query in raw() function

Tags: django, database

I'm trying to alter a table and add a new column in DJango models on runtime with Manager.raw() function but it isn't adding the column to sqLite DB. Can I achieve that functionality and if yes, how?
I'm using DJango 3.0

My code for above task is

```
from test.models import Test

date = datetime.today().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S')
Test.objects.raw('alter table test_test add column %s integer', [date])
```

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. You cannot alter table with raw() function because raw() function only handles `SELECT` queries and returns a QuerySet and gives error/doesn't do anything if cannot return something.

The way to alter table using SQL query is using `django.db.Connection` library and using its `cursor.execute()` function but the issue with that is the only way to store or retrieve values in that columns is to execute another query with `cursor.execute()` function and getting values through `cursor.fetchall()` function which negates the core advantage of using DJango as DJango website quotes:

> "Django makes it easier to build better Web apps more quickly and with
>   less code."

The documentation of DJango [raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/).

Another way I've found is to make a dynamic model and migrate it at runtime as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593541/django-how-to-migrate-dynamic-models-made-at-runtime) stackoverflow question. But this approach won't work in production unless the host has Python and all required libraries install and have access to CommandLine.

In the end, I'll say that dynamic DB structure is never a good approach and mostly start giving errors sooner or later. It should never be used unless very very important. I was just doing this for my practice and to understand Django more. Thank you.